# AWS Amplify returns generic Network Error on any Lambda failure

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-amplify

I'm building an app that connects with a serverless API on AWS (API Gateway/Lambda) via AWS Amplify used on a web (React) frontend.

When the request is successful, everything works just fine (definitionally, I suppose). There are no CORS issues or anything. But if I try to return a "failed" response, my frontend does not receive that response. It receives a generic `Network Error` with no information about what happened, and the console logs a failure.

I think the code will make more sense of this. I request to the API using code like this (Amplify configured elsewhere):

```
import { API } from 'aws-amplify';
...
API.get('apiName', path, options)
  .then(response => {
     // Whatever
  })
  .catch(err => {
     // Whatever
  })
```

In the Lambda, I'm returning (and Cloudwatch verifies this, as I log right before running `callback(null, responseObject)`) a full response object like this:

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
    },
    "body": "{ /* whatever */ }"
}
```

or this:

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
    },
    "body": "{ /* error here */ }"
}
```

In the `200` case, the response reaches my frontend perfectly (shows up in the `.then` function as `response`). In the `500` (or general error) case, the `.catch` is called *and* the `err` object is *not* what I put in the response body, but rather a generic `Network Error` with no relevant information (or status code):

```
Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
```

To clarify, simply *changing the `statusCode`* from 200 to 400 both means the request is caught on the frontend (good), and that the error has none of the information I'm returning from the Lambda (bad).

The console also logs errors:

```
DELETE https://abcdefg.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/development/my-endpoint 403 ()

Failed to load https://abcdefg.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/development/my-endpoint: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

It also logs stuff related to a CORS failure that makes no sense to me, because I'm following the **exact** same pattern as for success cases, just with a higher `statusCode`.

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://abcdefg.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/development/my-endpoint with MIME type application/json.
XHR failed loading: DELETE "https://abcdefg.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/development/my-endpoint".
```

Any idea what's going on here? It's really frustrating not to have access to the real informative error on the frontend. Please let me know if there's any other information that would be helpful for solving this issue.

**EDIT** -- following @Michael's feedback below, I checked to see if my app was using lambda or lambda-proxy, and it is, in fact, using lambda-proxy, which should *not* produce this behavior, as I understand it.

Here's some code in my serverless.yml file,

```
functions:
  projectsGetAll:
    handler: handlers/projects/getAll.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: projects
          method: get
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam
```

And here's a screenshot (with the endpoint whited out) from AWS API Gateway for one of these endpoints:

[image]

I want to confirm that this is, then, unexpected behavior for lambda-proxy. Is there possibly some setting that is mucking things up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out! The error object coming back (a generic `500` and `NetworkError` **contained** my constructed error, under the `response` key).

So if I log `error.response`, I get my fully constructed error object, with its own message and `statusCode`, even though the error object itself has a `code` of `500` and message of `Error: Network Error`, and the error catching process seems to throw out inaccurate error logs (CORB stuff) in the console.

Weird. Not sure if that's expected Lambda behavior, or something with Amplify, or something I'm doing wrong, but if anyone else runs into this issue, I hope this helps!

**EDIT** - Apparently that is expected Amplify behavior, which I missed in the docs.

But I figured out another issue that seems to be a bug. This response key only shows up when I **don't** specify `headers` in the request options. In other words, this request returns an `error` with a `response` key:

```
API.get('my-api', '/path')
```

But this one returns an error without the key:

```
API.get('my-api', '/path', { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } })
```

Very weird, but true for me. Even **other** options are fine, but the headers option seems to mess things up (and only for the error response).

Comment: Thanks for following up on this @Sasha - I am currently suffering from the same problem and not getting the error with the key even without the headers - have you had any issues with this code where you've had to patch for this?

Answer (score 1):

This does end up depending on how you configure your API Gateway, e.g. Lambda proxy etc. If you are NOT using a Lambda proxy setup, you will need to map these error responses/codes within API Gateway, see extensive post on that here:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/error-handling-patterns-in-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/

If you are using a Lambda Proxy, you will just return as a specific type of proxy response from Lambda: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html

Comment: Added edit above -- I'm configured for lambda-proxy, so that doesn't seem to be it, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

If you're using API Gateway and are running into this issue, make sure you update the API Gateway's "Gateway Responses" Default 5XX and Default 4XX headers to contain correct response headers (and/or messages) -- or else `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` will not be sent on error responses and your browser will throw "Network Error".

For example, set response headers for Default 5XX and 4XX to:

```
Response header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Value: '*'
```

Updating these default header values resolved my issue, now proper error messages are being resolved.